# Spring MVC Different CustomDateEditor Binders for Various Fields

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my Controller I bind a main Date Custom editor that works for most fields, but not all: **yyyy-MM-dd:**

```
@InitBinder      
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) 
{  
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

I also have some GUI fields that map to a Date in my domain object, but they are different. Some are in **yyyy** format (Year only). They require a customized Date binder.

Is it possible to define other CustomDateEditors that bind to specific fields, rather than a one-for-all Type binder?

Comment: Use `binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "field.path", editor);`. [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.beans.PropertyEditor-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other way is to use Spring [Formatter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html) instead PropertyEditors. 
The good thing is, that Spring [has already formatters for `Date`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-conversion) ([`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html)) and the next good thing is, that they are configured per attribute, by annotation.

For example

```
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy")
   private Date yearOnly;

   @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
   private Date dayMonthYear;
```